# How to use .env vars in template string

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, template-strings

Using `.env` vars is straightforward as a key-value pair if you have setting defined as below in a `js` file.

```
export default {
  host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
  port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
  }
};
```

However, I am wondering how can I use a `.env` var in a template string.

Example

```
context.mailer.sendMail({
  from: `${settings.app.name} <${process.env.EMAIL_HOST}>`,
  to: user.email,
  subject: 'Subject',
  html: 'Some html',
});
```

Over here `settings.app.name` is defined in the config file

```
export default {
  name: 'AppName',
};
```

However, I can not use `process.env.EMAIL_HOST` in the `from` field as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the template string I posted in my original question is correct. The error was in the wrong `.env` key name.

No more answers are needed for this question now. Thanks!